# Weird rendering of backgrounds of elements nested in a table with "table-layout: fixed"

Tags: css, css-position, html-table, html-email

I'm trying to make two elements overlap **without** using the `position` CSS property because it isn't supported by email clients. I've basically solved it by using a table with `table-layout: fixed`. See the code snippet below (the `position`-based implementation is there too, just for the sake of comparison). However, when these elements aren't empty, it doesn't work exactly the way I want it to. See the picture or run the snippet to see. While the content of the blue block does overlap the red block's both background and content, the background of the blue block is rendered **under** the content of the red block, overlapping only its background (and the border). Can anyone think of a way to make it overlap the content as well?

It works the same way in Chrome, Firefox and IE11, so I believe it's not a random implementation of an undefined behavior. There must exist some logic behind this. Why do backgrounds of elements nested in `td`s behave in such a strange way? I'm really surprised to learn that something can sneak in between an element's content and background.

Note: negative margins can't be a solution as they're not supported by mail clients.

[image: Figure 1]

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#a, #aa { border: 1px #faa solid; color: #800; width: 95px; height: 180px; background: #fcc; }
#b, #bb { border: 1px #aaf solid; color: #008; width: 100px; height: 150px; background: #ccf; }
#a { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 200px; }
#b { position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 270px; }

#t { table-layout: fixed; width: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; }
#atd, #btd { vertical-align: top; padding: 0; }
#bb { margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 70px; }  /* OR #btd { padding-top: 50px; padding-left: 70px; } */
```

```html
<div id=a>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/40">Nullam lectus ante, auctor id lacinia vitae.
</div>
<div id=b>Proin laoreet convallis odio, a tempus sem faucibus ut. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus.</div>

<table id=t>
  <tr>
    <td id=atd>
      <div id=aa>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/40">Nullam lectus ante, auctor id lacinia vitae.
      </div>
    </td>
    <td id=btd>
      <div id=bb>Proin laoreet convallis odio, a tempus sem faucibus ut. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Then only way is to use an image.

Comment: Some time ago I read a blog which recommended to use plain HTML structures for newsletters, because mail clients do not implement CSS rules reliably.

Comment: `table-layout` has solid support across the clients. See https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: There's a lot going on here that won't really be supported by "all" email clients. I have to ask, what is the purpose of overlaying tables like this in an email?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly might not work and in which client? As for the purpose, it's just an element of the design.